# Auto fill in dates with Excel based on ending Date

Tags: excel, time, autofill

I am trying to recreate my companies time sheet so that it includes the weekly hours and overtime calculations opposed to just the total hours of two weeks.

[Old Time sheet Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLzn4.png)
[image: Old Time sheet Format]

Unfortunately, the file we use is locked, so I can't just edit it or see the formulas, so I am recreating it from scratch. I've got it all figured out, except for the date calculations. The current sheet is set so when we enter the pay period ending in :(Insert Date)

The columns automatically calculate all the appropriate dates in a format like `Dec 05, Sat` with the day (`Sat`) being on a second line.

I have almost figured out a solution, in that I made the last day of the sheet (Q9) equal to the entered value (C8), and then each previous day was simply calculated as (Q9-1) (changing per column obviously)

Well, this successfully changed the dates, but it is in the `12/5/15` format opposed to `DEC 05, Sat` format:

[New Time Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GMI3.png)
[image: New Time Sheet]

Changing the format to date, just made all the dates equal as the formula did not calculate and I haven't been able to get the day to display with the date.

I have the days manually typed in, because our pay period always ends on a Friday, but I would like to figure out how to set it up for situations in which the day may be other than Friday.

Comment: your formatting solution did the trick, I summarized below, but i can't accept my own answer

Comment: well, i searched for an excel thing, but searches brought me to this.  

I wouldnt have has to ask at all if the custom dates format I was using actually worked properly. I wasnt sure if I had to do some advanced programming to do what I wanted to do or not. 

Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatting suggestion helped from PNUTS

I had working formula's but the Date format was messing them up.

I did the custom formate of the date row to  mmm dd, and the Day row, as ddd, as suggested.

I made the Day row = the Date row, so the days will change with the date.

Thanks

[Formula setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0bsZ.png)